# Detect div size (height) while filling content (from database)

Tags: jquery, html

I want to detect the div size height while filling content (from database). If the div height exeed 800px, then draw new div as new content wrapper and fill the remain content inside. The illustration is like the following :

Single content wrapper produced height (vary) let's say 2500 px for example (could be more)

```
<div id="content-wrapper>
p 1
p 2
p 3
p 4
p 5
p 6
p 8
p 9
</div>
```

i want to divide it with 800 px each so it will produced multiple div container (content wrapper) like the following.

```
<div id="content-wrapper>
p 1
part of p 2

[reached 800px here] --> break 1, print </div><div id="content-wrapper">

remaining part of p2...
p 3
p 4
p 5

[reached 800px here] --> break 2, print </div><div id="content-wrapper">

remaining part of p 5
p 6
p 7
p 8

[reached 800px here] --> break 3, print </div><div id="content-wrapper">
p 9

</div>
```

From the example above while loading the content it meet 3 time 800 px height. So it will print 4 content wrapper on the page.

How to do the trick with jQuery and css ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what i try to achieve is so the content look like displayed in pages, instead of single long down page.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the height of your div with offsetHeight

```
var contentwrapper = $("#content-wrapper");
var height = contentwrapper.offsetHeight;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you are using the same ID again! An ID is used for an unique element, if you want to reuse it again, use CSS classes.

Comment: i use var divSize = $('#content-wrapper').css('height'); to get the single div size. But how to break it while loading content in it ? that's my problem.

Comment: Are you loading the content dynamically? (AJAX/JS)

Comment: Yes the content to be loaded is dynamic. And the content produced vary height inside the content-wrapper div (single).